# Is there some other way to access Stack Exchange inbox?

Tags: support, global-inbox

Accessing the inbox by clicking on the Stack Exchange icon at the top of the page appears to be broken at the moment (it shows an empty inbox, even if there are updates).

Is there some other way to access the inbox?

Comment: OS? Browser? Does a hard refresh help? It works fine for me on XP w/ Firefox.

Comment: Works fine for me, Chrome / Win 7.

Comment: I'm running Firefox / Win 7 and I am NOT getting the inbox to load anything, so I am having a similar issue as the OP.

Comment: It does not work for me and I am using Chrome on Win 7.

Comment: Works fine for me too, Firefox / XP ;-)

Comment: I'm having the [same problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166988/not-seeing-anything-in-my-inbox).

Comment: I *had* the same problem with Firefox on Linux. Luckily, it seems to be solved now: I can access my inbox normally again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access your global inbox through your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/270089/kjo) (look for the "inbox" tab).