# Not seeing anything in my inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

On all Stackexchange sites, I'm not seeing anything in my inbox.  The "hot questions", "all sites", and "notifications" drop-downs are showing up normally. I know that my inbox is not empty.

I see this with both Chrome and IE9, both on Windows 7.

[image: all sites]

[image: inbox]

**Update:**

Curiouser and curiouser:

[image: inbox with just one item]

**Update 2:**

Also reproduced (with the single item) with Chrome on Linux and iOS (iPad 1), and Safari on iOS.

Comment: No repro on Chrome (latest stable) on Win7, but this has been [reported again earlier today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166981/is-there-some-other-way-to-access-stack-exchange-inbox).

Comment: The same was reported (and fixed) here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166947/stackexchange-inbox-dissapeared

Comment: @user000001: Yes, it's ok now.

Comment: I got kicked out twice and had to login again but now it's working here as well.